# Should copy assignment operator leverage std::swap as a general rule?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it a good general practice to always implement my copy assignment operators using `std::swap`? My understanding is that this provides a way to share the copy constructor implementation. I'd like to avoid duplicating the actual copy logic itself. So here is what I'd do:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Foo const& other) { /* assume valid implementation */ }

    Foo& operator= (Foo other)
    {
        std::swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The act of passing "other" into the assignment operator performs copy construction (we've shared the copy logic at this point). I assume the swap will invoke move construction (which has a compiler-generated implementation here).

I've been doing this to pretty much every class I implement copy construction for, since the assignment & constructor never have different implementations.

Comment: Yes, copy and swap idiom is a good one for any resource owning class. Another benefit is the strong exception guarantee that you get from the swap. Being a "general rule" for a code base if more opinion based, imo.

Comment: You should be `using namespace std;` before `swap` and remove the `std::`. That way a more specific `swap` is used if available. Other than that this is pretty standard.

Comment: Some people argue that implementing special member functions in terms of `swap` is not optimal. There are some unnecessary assignments since `swap` brings `other` into some specific state. Also, assignment operators providing the strong exception guarantee might be a pessimization: The user might not need that guarantee, but they'll pay for it in any case.

Comment: @dyp Good point but I'd argue from a design perspective that going back and making things exception safe later is a big pain and sometimes it's not something you can do without discussing complete rewrites. Like localization and many other foundational things, it's something best to do up front.

Comment: "(which has a compiler-generated implementation here)." -- you blocked your compiler-generated implementation in your sample code.  If you intend to have it, add the proper `=default`

Comment: @Yakk strangely I do not define any move construction/assignment in my classes and the `swap()` call does not fail to compile. Why would it still work?

Comment: Copy constructor is a valid fall back move constructor.  Your `operator=` is a valid move assign.

Comment: @Yakk where are the rules for this defined? I assume there is some sort of precedence... i.e. it will try true move construction first, if that isn't there, it will try lvalue reference, then lvalue?

Comment: @void.pointer This isn't about "making things exception safe", it's about *which* exception guarantee you want to provide for you assignment-operator: The strong one (if something goes wrong, there are no effects) or the basic one (no resources are leaked).

Comment: @void.pointer whuch it calls is just overloading: `T` and `T const&` are valid for an arg of type `T&&`.  Which is generated... should be a stack overflow answer somewhere around here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code does not have a move constructor.  Your copy constructor blocks the automatic creation of a move constructor, and attempting to move your class instead copies it.

For move-assign, your `operator=` also blocks its automatic implementation, and can be used in its place.

The end result is [an infinite recursive call of `=` (live code)](http://ideone.com/VJKQUZ).

If you follow the rule of 0, you need neither a copy constructor, move constructor, move-assignment, copy-assignment, or destructor.  If you write any of them, you should be prepared to write all of them.

Using `std::swap` can be useful, but because you have to write your move-assign and move-construct, doing either in terms of `std::swap` is an infinite recursion waiting to happen.

Comment: o.O You're right: You cannot implement `operator=` in terms of `std::swap`; you can implement it in terms of your *own* ("optimized") `swap`. The usual copy-and-swap idiom for operators uses a custom `swap` (member function).

Comment: I think if I just add the move constructor, that fixes the infinite recursion (good catch btw). Move assignment will still be a copy, but the swap will end up using the move constructor, right?

Comment: @void.pointer `std::swap` does this: `swap(A& a, A& b) { A tmp( move(a) ); a = move(b); b = move(tmp); }` So it needs a move assignment-operator.

Comment: @dyp:  Technically, `std::swap` needs `T` to be *move assignable*.  `T` does not need a move assignment operator to be move assignable.  For example a copy assignment operator can fulfill the move assignable requirement.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Hmm, that was intended as a simplification, but it oversimplified. It should say "So it calls an assignment-operator." (which then leads to infinite recursion in the OP's code) -- this is still a simplification, since e.g., for trivially copyable types it's not required to call an operator.

Comment: @dyp: I've read enough of your posts to know that you know this. It is just that when slightly incorrect things get repeated, newbies tend to believe them to be completely correct.  E.g. the copy swap idiom is the best way to implement assignment... ;-)

Answer (score 9):

If `Foo` contains non-static data members `std::vector` or `std::string`, or contains data members that contain `vector` or `string` (i.e. even indirectly), then this can be a *very* effective way to slow your code down.  It can even be more effective than calling `std::sleep_for` as the latter doesn't waste battery power on mobile devices.

The reason is that a copy assignment which calls the `vector` or `string` copy assignment has the chance to reuse the container's capacity.  Whereas the `swap` idiom *always* throws away capacity.

For more info, see my [ACCU 2014 talk, slides 43-53](http://accu.org/content/conf2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf).

In particular, note this performance chart which shows the speed increase of calling `vector`'s copy assignment operator vs doing the copy/swap idiom with a `vector` data member.

[this http://howardhinnant.github.io/accu_2014_48.pdf](http://howardhinnant.github.io/accu_2014_48.pdf)

At best, the copy/swap idiom is as fast as using `vector`'s copy assignment (when capacity is never sufficient).  At worst (when capacity is always sufficient), copy/swap is nearly 8X slower.  On average, copy/swap entails a 70% speed hit (for this test).

Comment: I think this comes down to whether or not you want/need to provide the strong exception guarantee. But IIRC, you're in favor of external control à la `strong_assign`.

Comment: Just linking to this question with further discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463356/copy-swap-idiom-not-recommended