# When is copy-and-swap idiom not applicable

Tags: c++, copy-and-swap

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) about the copy-and-swap idiom I've read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator) which says under (2):

```
class_name & class_name :: operator= ( const class_name & )     (2)
```

> (2) Typical declaration of a copy assignment operator when
>   copy-and-swap idiom **cannot be used**

When should we avoid using the copy-and-swap idiom ?

And when it "cannot be used" altogether?

Are there real life cases where both copy-and-swap and rule-of-zero are not applicable?

I did find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23918469/is-copy-and-swap-always-the-best-solution) but it was too specific and did not include any guideline as to how to identify such cases.

Comment: Typically, copy-and-swap is *easy* and *safe*, but perhaps not optimal from a speed perspective.  For example, assigning two containers of a million elements, it's probably faster to do a million assignments than to do a million constructions and a million destructions.

Comment: @user2079303 thanks, that sentence was drunk it had to go home. Hope now it's clearer

Comment: Real life cases where copy/swap kills your performance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25942402/576911

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When should we avoid using the copy-and-swap idiom ?

When you can prove that naïve copy is safe and faster than `swap`.

You can identify the case when there are no member pointers (neither smart nor raw) that own objects and same is true for all member objects.

> And when it "cannot be used" altogether?

Copy-and-swap cannot be used when the type is not [swappable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Swappable).

To be swappable, the type must be either move-constructible and move-assignable, or you must have defined a `swap` member function or a friend function.

Answer (score 2):

Your link describing the potential implementations of an assignment operator described `class_name& class_name::operator=(class_name)` as:

> Typical declaration of a copy assignment operator when copy-and-swap idiom can be used

And `class_name& class_name::operator=(const class_name&)` as:

> Typical declaration of a copy assignment operator when copy-and-swap idiom cannot be used

Basically we would always want to use copy-and-swap when possible, as mentioned in the [excellent answer to your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/2642059), because it will pass the self-assignment test.

So now the question is why the convention mentioned on http://www.cppreference.com?

Let's say I'm implementing a copy constructor to a virtual class, and I want to make it clear to anyone who will inherit that they should use the copy-and-swap idiom. How would I do that? I could help them by doing the copy for them in the initial call:

```
class_name& class_name::operator=(class_name)
```

This is a copy by value, so the implementer of any child classes would see that I've already made the copy for them so all they'll need to do is swap.

Now, what if I had a `class_name` which contained a member which could not be copy constructed, for example what if my class has a [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) such that it cannot be copy-constructed. I can indicate that by *not* making a copy by value argument to the assignment operator, for example:

```
class_name& class_name::operator(const class_name&)
```

Indicating it will be on implementer of any child classes to ensure that sufficient checking is done to pass the self-assignment test.